# Can you prove this inequality for positive-definite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two positive definite matrices $A=(A_{ij})$ and $B=(B_{ij})$ prove that $A_{ij}\leq (\sum_{k,l}A_{kl}B_{kl})(B^{-1})_{ij}$ for each $i,j$.

My idea was to first observe that this is trivial if the two matrices are diagonal. Then show that diagonalization does not affect the inequality. But I could not prove the latter.

Comment: Does $B_{ij}^{-1}$ mean $(B_{ij})^{-1}$ or $(B^{-1})_{ij}$?

Comment: @user1551 fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality does not always hold. Let $A=B$ be any matrix that is both positive definite and entrywise positive. Then $B^{-1}$ must contain some negative off-diagonal entries. Hence the LHS of the inequality is positive but the RHS is negative for some $(i,j)$. E.g. when $A=B=\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&1}$, we have
$$
A_{12}=1>-7
=\operatorname{tr}(AB)\left(B^{-1}\right)_{12}
=\left(\sum_{k,l}A_{kl}B_{kl}\right)\left(B^{-1}\right)_{12}.
$$